# R lattice - trying to change labels colors with y.scale.components customisation

Tags: r, colors, label, lattice

I currently try to customise a lattice parallel plot, by changing its Y axis label colors, depending on the character of these same lables. I created a customised y.scale.components function, as described in many books/forums. However, after assigning a vector of new colors to the ans$left$labels$col parameter, only default color (black) is used for the plot.

Here's the code:

```
test2 <- read.table(textConnection("

         species  evalue l1 l2  l3
   Daphnia.pulex  1.0E-6 17 41  35
   Daphnia.pulex 1.0E-10 11 30  25
   Daphnia.pulex 1.0E-20  4 14  17
   Daphnia.pulex 1.0E-35  4  8  15
   Daphnia.pulex 1.0E-50  1  4   8
   Daphnia.pulex 1.0E-75  0  2   6
Ixodes.scapularis  1.0E-6  7 20 118
Ixodes.scapularis 1.0E-10  6 17 107
Ixodes.scapularis 1.0E-20  4  6  46
Ixodes.scapularis 1.0E-35  2  3  14
Ixodes.scapularis 1.0E-50  0  0   5
Ixodes.scapularis 1.0E-75  0  0   2
")->con,header=T);close(con)

#data.frame to assign a color to the data, depending on species names on y axis
orga<-c("Daphnia.pulex","Ixodes.scapularis")
color<-c("cornsilk2","darkolivegreen1" );
phylum<-c("arthropoda","arthropoda" );
colorChooser<-data.frame(orga,color,phylum)

#fonction for custom rendering of left y axis labels 
yscale.components.custom<-function(...) {
  ans<-yscale.components.default(...)
  #vector for new label colors, grey60 by default
  new_colors<-c()
  new_colors<-rep("grey60",length(ans$left$labels$labels))
  # the for() check all labels character and assign the corresponding color with the colorChooser data.frame
  n<-1
  for (i in ans$left$labels$labels) {
      new_colors[n]<-as.character(colorChooser$color[colorChooser$orga==i])
      #got the color corresponding to the label, with the colorChooser dataframe
  n<-n+1
  }
  print(length(new_colors))
  cat(new_colors,sep="\n")  #print the content of the generated color vector
  ans$left$labels$col<-new_colors  #assign this vector to col parameter
  ans
}

#plot everything
bwplot(   reorder(species,l1,median)~l1,
      data=test2,
      panel = function(..., box.ratio) {
            panel.grid(h=length(colnames(cdata[,annot.arthro]))-1,v=0,col.line="grey80")
            panel.violin(..., col = "white",varwidth = FALSE, box.ratio = box.ratio )
            panel.bwplot(..., fill = NULL, box.ratio = .07)
      },
      yscale.components=yscale.components.custom
)
```

Here's the output of the cat() command, included in the yscale.components.custom function. As you can see, it outputs two times the color labels, but the vector assigned to ans$left$labels$col is of length 2. Is there a second call that setup the Y axis labels colors ? where does it come from ?

```
[1] 2
darkolivegreen1
cornsilk2
[1] 2
darkolivegreen1
cornsilk2
```

Any help is welcome, i don't undestand why the colors are assigned to ans$left$labels$col but everything is drawn in blacK. I would like also to change the violin border colors, using the same colorChooser data.frame, but that's another story...

Answer (score 3):

After asking to Deepayan Sarkar, the ans$left$labels$col value is apparently ignored during lattice execution.

I used a different solution with the "scales" argument. Unfortunately, I cannot anymore rely on the lattice reorder function to reorder my data series by their median.

For the code mentionned above, I order them manually, then create a vector of color with the corresponding order. I cannot rely on the lattice reordering anymore (the "reorder" in my lattice formula). Then, I setup my axix labels colors with

```
scales=list(col=c(color1,color2,...))
```

Comment: Points for asking the package author.